# Dash traceback not leading to any line in my code

Tags: python, pandas, plotly-dash

I am working on my first Dash app. I am getting the following error:

```
"Cannot set a frame with no defined index "
```

The issue is that the traceback doesn’t lead to any line in my code. It only goes through installed libraries:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3540, in _ensure_valid_index
    value = Series(value)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 316, in __init__
    data = SingleBlockManager(data, index, fastpath=True)
  File "C:\Users\LIAG8802\Documents\Procurement_analytics\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1516, in __init__
    block = make_block(block, placement=slice(0, len(axis)), ndim=1)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 3284, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 2792, in __init__
    super().__init__(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 128, in __init__
    "{mgr}".format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs))
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 3, placement implies 0

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3543, in _ensure_valid_index
    "Cannot set a frame with no defined index "
ValueError: Cannot set a frame with no defined index and a value that cannot be converted to a Series
```

How can I know which line in my code is causing the error? Note that I found out what the problem was but I want to know how I could have traced it more easily.

EDIT: note that I cannot track the issue putting `print`s at several lines since the error pops out in the `dash` debug console, not in the `anaconda` console which does not crash

Comment: put `print()` with different messages in different lines and see which one will be displayed as last before error.

Comment: @furas I thought of this but the issue is that the error pops out in the `dash` debug console, not in the `anaconda` console which does not crash

Comment: could you give the code you wrote so we can try to reproduce the error? i would say it's a panda error caused by the data you feed but i can't be sure.

Comment: @Frayal it seems that it was because I was trying to save an empty dataframe into my SQL table but what I am really interested in is this traceback issue.

Comment: the traceback tells you that there is an issue when creating the panda dataFrame (referred to as frame here). Slice of a dataFrame is a Serie. the link between those series are the index. If an index cannot be set or the data cannot be sliced into series, pandas will raise an error. you can look into the build function for pd.DataFrame() here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.25.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L305-L8476